# Postgres: difference between two timestamps (hours:minutes:seconds)

Tags: postgresql, date-difference

i'm creating a select that calculate the difference between two timestamps

here the code: (isn't necessary you understand tables below. Just follow the thread)

```
  (select value from demo.data where id=q.id and key='timestampend')::timestamp 
- (select value from demo.data where id=q.id and key='timestampstart')::timestamp) as durata
```

Look at this example, if you want easier:

```
select timestamp_end::timestamp - timestamp_start as duration
```

---

here the result:

[image: 1]]
// "durata" is duration

The problem is that the first timestamp is 2017-06-21 and the second is 2017-06-22 so we have 1 day and some hours of difference.
How can i do for show the result not like "1 day 02:06:41.993657"  but "26:06:41.993657" without milliseconds (26:06:41)?

---

---

Update
I'm testing this query:

```
select id as ticketid,
(select value from demo.data where id=q.id and key = 'timestampstart')::timestamp as TEnd,
(select value from demo.data where id=q.id and key = 'timestampend')::timestamp as TStart,
(select
make_interval
(
0,0,0,0, -- years, months, weeks, days
extract(days from duration1)::int * 24 + extract(hours from duration1)::int, -- calculated hours (days * 24 + hours)
extract(mins from duration1)::int, -- minutes
floor(extract(secs from duration1))::int -- seconds, without miliseconds, thus FLOOR()
) as duration1
from
(
(select value from demo.data where id=q.id and key='timestampstart')::timestamp - (select value from demo.data where id=q.id and key='timestampend')::timestamp
) t(duration) as dur
from (select distinct id from demo.data) q
```

error is the same: **[Err] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "::"**
there is an error on id = q.id

data table is like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use `EXTRACT` function and wrap it up with `MAKE_INTERVAL` and some math. It's pretty straight forward, since you pass each part of timestamp to it:

```
select 
  make_interval(
    0,0,0,0, -- years, months, weeks, days
    extract(days from durdata)::int * 24 + extract(hours from durdata)::int, -- calculated hours (days * 24 + hours)
    extract(mins from durdata)::int, -- minutes
    floor(extract(secs from durdata))::int -- seconds, without miliseconds, thus FLOOR()
    ) as durdata
from (
  select '2017-06-22 02:06:41.993657'::timestamp - '2017-06-21'::timestamp
  ) t(durdata);
```

Output:

```
 durdata
----------
 26:06:41
```

---

You could wrap it up within a function to make it easy to work with.
There is no worry about `timestamp - timestamp` returning an output with precision to more than days, and thus losing you some information, because even calculation for different years would still return days and additional time part.

Example:

```
postgres=# select ('2019-06-22 01:03:05.993657'::timestamp - '2017-06-21'::timestamp) as durdata;
        durdata
------------------------
 731 days 01:03:05.993657
```

Comment: Your code is working with manual timestamps but I found this error if I use db column: **ERROR:  syntax error at or near "::"**  here the code: `from (
  (select value from demo.data where id=q.id and key='timestampend')::timestamp - 
  (select value from demo.data where id=q.id and key='timestampstart')::timestamp
  ) t(durdata)) from (select distinct id from demo.data) q`  demo.data is json table format, there is an "id", "key" and "value"

Comment: You need to inspect what "value" does it return.

Comment: Attach sample data for your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, although interval data type allows having hours value greater than 23 (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-formatting.html), to_char() function will cut out days and will take only "hours within a day" if you put delta value to it and try to get 'HH24' value.

So, I ended up with such trick, combining to_char(...) with extract('epoch' from...) and then putting the concatinated value to another to_char():

```
with timestamps(ts1, ts2) as (
  select
    '2017-06-21'::timestamptz,
    '2017-06-22 01:03:05.1212'::timestamptz
), res as (
  select
    round(extract('epoch' from ts2 - ts1) / 3600) as hours,
    to_char(ts2 - ts1, 'MI:SS') as min_sec
  from timestamps
)
select hours, min_sec, to_char(format('%s:%s', hours, min_sec)::interval, 'HH24:MI:SS')
from res;
```

The result is:

```
 hours | min_sec | to_char
-------+---------+----------
    25 | 03:05   | 25:03:05
(1 row)
```

You can define an SQL function to make using it easier:

```
create or replace function extract_hhmmss(timestamptz, timestamptz) returns interval as $$
  with delta(i) as (
    select
      case when $2 > $1 then $2 - $1
      else $1 - $2
      end
  ), res as (
    select
      round(extract('epoch' from i) / 3600) as hours,
      to_char(i, 'MI:SS') as min_sec
    from delta
  )
  select
    (
      case when $2 < $1 then '-' else '' end
      || to_char(format('%s:%s', hours, min_sec)::interval, 'HH24:MI:SS')
    )::interval
  from res;
$$ language sql stable;
```

Example of usage:

```
[local]:5432 nikolay@test=# select extract_hhmmss('2017-06-21'::timestamptz, '2017-06-22 01:03:05.1212'::timestamptz);
 extract_hhmmss
----------------
 25:03:05
(1 row)

Time: 0.882 ms
[local]:5432 nikolay@test=# select extract_hhmmss('2017-06-22 01:03:05.1212'::timestamptz, '2017-06-21'::timestamptz);
 extract_hhmmss
----------------
 -25:03:05
(1 row)
```

Notice, that it will give an error if timestamps are provided in reverse order, but it's not really hard to fix. // Update: already fixed.